# Monotonic functions have only jump discontinuities proof (stuck on the last step)

Tags: limits, continuity

I want to show, that monotonic functions only have jump discontinuities.

By the definition of discontinuity, this assumption must fail:
$$\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)\ne f(x_0)\;.$$
where $f(x)$ is our monotonic decreasing function and is discontinuous at $x_0\in[a,b]$.

Right and left limits exist (because of completeness of $R$) and are equal to:
 $$\lim_{x \to p^+}f(x)=\inf\{f(x) \mid x \gt p\}\quad \mbox{and} \quad \lim_{x \to p^-}f(p)=\sup \{f(x) \mid x \lt p\}$$

and I know how to prove it.

The only thing, that I don't know how to show is why $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}f(x)$ fails. I am sure it's connected with definitions of supremum and infimum, but i cannot come to the right conclusions.

Can you give me a hint?

Comment: It seems you took an arbitrary $p \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ is discontinuous at $p$ and showed that left and right limits exist. This is enough to state that it is a jump discontinuity. Why would you need anything else?

Comment: @Adayah I want to show, that left and right limits are not equal (definition of jump discontinuity). I don't know how to prove it

Comment: Ah, you're right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disambiguation: it seems that you're using $x_0, p, c$ for the same point. I will just use $p$. ;-)

Note that by monotonicity

$$\lim_{x \to p^-} f(x) = \sup \{ f(x) : x < p \} \leqslant f(p) \leqslant \inf \{ f(x) : x > p \} = \lim_{x \to p^+} f(x)$$

so if the one-sided limits were equal, then they would equal $f(p)$, so $f$ would be continuous at $p$, which by assumption it does not.